# WCF and IIS error 500 when using diagnostics

Tags: wcf, iis, system.diagnostics

I have problem with WCF on IIS when using diagnostics.

When I call the service I get the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote
>   server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error..

If I remove "system.diagnostics" section I dont get error 500 but I get an error

> The requested service,
>   'http://localhost/CustomerServiceSite/Customer.svc'
>   could not be activated. See the
>   server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information..

Which obviously needs diagnostics to get fixed.

Any idea why diagnostics doesnt work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check event log on web server - http 500 should be logged there. Also check that Account running your AppPool in IIS has access rights to file used for diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostics will write a trace file to disk - maybe the user account WCF/ASP.NET is running under doesn't have permissions to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

If I opened my service in browser (http://localhost/CustomerServiceSite/Customer.svc) I have seen the whole error.

The problem was becouse I used NHibernate and Diagnostics in wrong way. Commenting NHibernate configuration solved my problem.